Detect collision and run a function in pymunk
I have a simple setup in pymunk where a circle collides with a segment. On every collision the radius of the circle should increase by an amount I specify (5% in this case). The circle should bounce correctly from the segment even after the radius increases. Here is my implementation but I am facing an issue where this code works erratically. Sometimes the radius increases on collision and sometimes it does not and I can't figure out why.
import pygame as pg
import pymunk
import pymunk.pygame_util
import sys
import math

pymunk.pygame_util.positive_y_is_up = False

RES = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1080 // 2, 1920 // 2
FPS = 120

pg.init()
surface = pg.display.set_mode(RES)
clock = pg.time.Clock()
draw_options = pymunk.pygame_util.DrawOptions(surface)

space = pymunk.Space()
space.gravity = 0, 530
elasticity = 0.999
friction = 0.05

# create the bounding box
def create_segments(start, end):
    segment_shape = pymunk.Segment(space.static_body, start, end, 3)
    segment_shape.elasticity = elasticity
    segment_shape.friction = friction
    segment_shape.collision_type = 1  # Assign a collision type to the walls
    space.add(segment_shape)

create_segments((0, HEIGHT), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))  # floor
create_segments((0, 0), (0, HEIGHT))  # left wall
create_segments((WIDTH, 0), (WIDTH, HEIGHT))  # right wall
create_segments((0, 0), (WIDTH, 0))  # ceiling

# create the ball
ball_mass = 1
ball_radius = 20 # Separate variable to store the radius
ball_moment = pymunk.moment_for_circle(ball_mass, 0, ball_radius)
ball_body = pymunk.Body(ball_mass, ball_moment)
ball_body.position = WIDTH // 2, 50
ball_body.velocity = (400, 200)
ball_shape = pymunk.Circle(ball_body, ball_radius)
ball_shape.elasticity = elasticity
ball_shape.friction = friction
ball_shape.collision_type = 2  # Assign a different collision type to the ball
space.add(ball_body, ball_shape)

#Collision handler
collided = False # Flag to track if collision happened in the current frame
def collision_handler(arbiter, space, data):
    global ball_radius, ball_shape, collided  

    if collided:
        return False

    # Calculate new radius
    new_radius = ball_radius * 1.05 # 5% increase

    # Adjust the ball's position based on the collision direction
    normal = arbiter.contact_point_set.normal
    if normal.y > 0:  # Collision with floor
        ball_body.position += (0, new_radius - ball_radius)
    elif normal.y < 0:  # Collision with ceiling
        ball_body.position -= (0, new_radius - ball_radius)
    elif normal.x > 0:  # Collision with right wall
        ball_body.position += (new_radius - ball_radius, 0)
    elif normal.x < 0:  # Collision with left wall
        ball_body.position -= (new_radius - ball_radius, 0)

    # Now check against the limits after adjusting the position
    if new_radius > ball_body.position[0] or new_radius > ball_body.position[1] or \
       new_radius > WIDTH - ball_body.position[0] or new_radius > HEIGHT - ball_body.position[1]:
       return True  # Reject radius increase if it exceeds space limits

    # Increase the radius
    ball_radius = new_radius
    
    # Remove the old ball shape
    space.remove(ball_shape)

    # Create the new ball shape
    ball_shape = pymunk.Circle(ball_body, ball_radius)
    ball_shape.elasticity = elasticity
    ball_shape.friction = friction
    ball_shape.collision_type = 2  # Assign the same collision type as before
    space.add(ball_shape)

    collided = True
    return True

# Add collision handler for the ball hitting the walls
handler = space.add_collision_handler(1, 2) # Only handle collisions between types 1 and 2
handler.pre_solve = collision_handler  # Use pre_solve instead of post_solve

# Main loop
while True:
    surface.fill(pg.Color('white'))

    for i in pg.event.get():
        if i.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()

    collided = False
    space.step(1 / FPS)
    space.debug_draw(draw_options)

    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

I have some other parts of code where I check and display the radius and that's how I was able to tell that the radius is not increasing on every bounce. For simplicity I've only included the relevant parts of the code here. I believe it is something to do with my collision handling logic but I am not able to troubleshoot.

I can think of a couple of things to try:

Use the begin handler instead of pre/post solve. You only want the size increase to trigger once per collision, right? So if a object rests on the ground, pre and post solve will be called each time step. Even in a bouncy simulation like yours, collisions can last more than one step.

Use the separate handler instead of pre/post/begin handler :) Then the collision response is already calculated and the ball is just about to stop touching. This way you are sure collision happened, and that you dont introduce some strangeness by manually moving the ball in the middle of the collision resolve logic.

Instead of replacing the ball, increase its radius. Updating the radius is marked as "unsafe" in the API, but its still "better" than replacing the whole object.

Dont move the ball, instead let Pymunk move it as part of its collision solve logic. I dont think this will work well with separate handler, but maybe it can work well with the begin handler.



Thanks for the pointer. I'll try these out.

The separate handler seems to be much much better. It is detecting 90%+ of all the collisions and changing radius correctly. I wasn't able to figure out the radius increase part. Should I do it inside my collision function or main loop?

I would suggest you try with a begin handler, and inside that one you update the radius with unsafe_set_radius. And you can try to not even move it, just let it increase in size and let Pymunk figure it out. (or you continue with the move)

Awesome, this worked. I used the begin handler and did not move the ball myself but let pymunk figure it out.
